# Merging of various [token...] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I've just come across:

- [token](/questions/tagged/token) 485 questions
- [tokens](/questions/tagged/tokens) 71 questions

which I think could be merged together

Separately, so could:

- [tokenize](/questions/tagged/tokenize) 37 questions
- [tokenizing](/questions/tagged/tokenizing) 238 questions
- [tokenizer](/questions/tagged/tokenizer) 143 questions
- [tokenization](/questions/tagged/tokenization) 5 questions

and possibly

- [stringtokenizer](/questions/tagged/stringtokenizer) 87 questions

Comment: I created synonyms and merged all but `stringtokenizer` since that one is a specific class name as mentioned below.

Comment: Thanks @Bill, there's a tag wiki for `stringtokenizer` already and we're down to 7 ( I think ) non-Java that need to be altered :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I completely agree with merging all the tags you cite, *except* [stringtokenizer](/questions/tagged/stringtokenizer).

If at all, those questions need to be retagged manually because it looks like "StringTokenizer" is a specific Java thing ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758181/how-can-i-use-stringtokenizer-with-my-jtable), and [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647784/reading-a-long-type-from-a-text-file-in-java)), aside from generically referring to the tokenization of string types.

Note I'm not necessarily arguing that it is a *good* tag, just that it's not a synonym of the others you propose here.

Comment: Yes, fair point. There are some that are not Java, which'll I'll gradually move out. I've created a [Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stringtokenizer/info) to emphasise link to Java, which'll need approving :-)

Comment: @Ben: Voted to approve one of them, and instant-approved the other. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Cody, I'll have to find a couple of answers to downvote to get rid of the embarrassing 2 rep that's just given me... I didn't realise I would still get it for something like that.

Comment: @Ben: Yeah, any time one of your suggested edits gets approved, you get +2 reputation. That's true for edits to questions and answers when you're under 2k, but it continues to be true for tag wikis until you're over 20k. There's nothing embarrassing about it, though! We give it to *encourage* people to submit these edits.