# Please approve some minor-variation synonyms

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I see a few pending synonym requests which should be uncontroversial (hyphens, plurals, abbreviations), please approve them (and any similar ones you come accross).

- [buffer](/questions/tagged/buffer) ← [buffers](/questions/tagged/buffers)
- [eof](/questions/tagged/eof) ← [end-of-file](/questions/tagged/end-of-file)
- [functor](/questions/tagged/functor) ← [functors](/questions/tagged/functors)
- [gnumake](/questions/tagged/gnumake) ← [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make) (or the other direction)
- [interval](/questions/tagged/interval) ← [intervals](/questions/tagged/intervals)
- [null](/questions/tagged/null) ← [nullvalue](/questions/tagged/nullvalue), [nulls](/questions/tagged/nulls)
- [postback](/questions/tagged/postback) ← [postbacks](/questions/tagged/postbacks)

Comment: These ones are now synonomized and merged.  If anyone sees any more hyphen or pluralization synonyms suggested, feel free to add them as answers.  These are always an easy decision, so we can be done with them quickly.  I'll check back later for any responses.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, any chance of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126793/merging-of-various-token-tags ?

Answer (score 5):

As requested by Bill The Lizard, these are the ones I could find:

- [ab-testing](/questions/tagged/ab-testing) ← [abtesting](/questions/tagged/abtesting)
- [abstract-class](/questions/tagged/abstract-class) ← [abstract-classes](/questions/tagged/abstract-classes) (or the other way around)
- [accessors](/questions/tagged/accessors) ← [accessor](/questions/tagged/accessor) (or the other way around)
- [access-point](/questions/tagged/access-point) ← [accesspoint](/questions/tagged/accesspoint)
- [access-violation-exception](/questions/tagged/access-violation-exception) ← [accessviolationexception](/questions/tagged/accessviolationexception)
- [action-filters](/questions/tagged/action-filters) ← [actionfilter](/questions/tagged/actionfilter), [action-filter](/questions/tagged/action-filter)
- [actionlink](/questions/tagged/actionlink) ← [actionlinks](/questions/tagged/actionlinks) (or the other way around)
- [actionmailer](/questions/tagged/actionmailer) ← [action-mailer](/questions/tagged/action-mailer)
- [active-patterns](/questions/tagged/active-patterns) ← [active-pattern](/questions/tagged/active-pattern)
- [actors](/questions/tagged/actors) ← [actor](/questions/tagged/actor)
- [ado.net-data-services](/questions/tagged/ado.net-data-services) ← [ado-net-dataservices](/questions/tagged/ado-net-dataservices)
- [allocations](/questions/tagged/allocations) ← [allocation](/questions/tagged/allocation)
- [appstore](/questions/tagged/appstore) ← [app-store](/questions/tagged/app-store)
- [asp.net-mvc-controller](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-controller) ← [asp.net-mvc-controllers](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-controllers)
- [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) ← [badge](/questions/tagged/badge)
- [binary-search-trees](/questions/tagged/binary-search-trees) ← [binary-search-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree) (and, by the way, should be the master tag for [bst](/questions/tagged/bst))
- [bit-manipulation](/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation) ← [bit-operations](/questions/tagged/bit-operations) (and both to [bitwise-operators](/questions/tagged/bitwise-operators)?)
- [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) ← [bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark)
- [border](/questions/tagged/border) ← [borders](/questions/tagged/borders)
- [circular-reference](/questions/tagged/circular-reference) ← [circular-references](/questions/tagged/circular-references)
- [circular-references](/questions/tagged/circular-references) ← [circular-reference](/questions/tagged/circular-reference)
- [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) ← [comment](/questions/tagged/comment)
- [core-text](/questions/tagged/core-text) ← [coretext](/questions/tagged/coretext)
- [crash](/questions/tagged/crash) ← [crashes](/questions/tagged/crashes)
- [custom-modelbinder](/questions/tagged/custom-modelbinder) ← [custom-model-binder](/questions/tagged/custom-model-binder) (should be the other way round?)
- [integer](/questions/tagged/integer) ← [integers](/questions/tagged/integers)

Comment: Man, there should be some automated way of finding these.

Comment: The only ones I disagreed with were bit-manipulation ← bit-operations, and only because they're not 100% synonymous.  All the other synonyms here are created/merged.  (Those hyphenation ones can be really hard to spot.  Nice work!)